# Android: При попытке использовать yandex-login получаю ошибку

Tags: android

Всем привет. Проблема:
Есть https://github.com/yandexmobile/yandex-login-sdk-android yandex-login sdk для android.
Есть моё android приложение:

> minSdkVersion 24
> targetSdkVersion 33

Возникает ошибка в Android Studio:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
Полная:

```
Manifest merger failed : android:exported needs to be explicitly
specified for element
<activity#com.yandex.authsdk.internal.BrowserDataActivity>. Apps
targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit
value for android:exported when the corresponding component has an
intent filter defined.
```

Создал "issue" https://github.com/yandexmobile/yandex-login-sdk-android/issues/15
Пытался подключить код библиотеки в проект, но это тоже не получается сделать.
Ощущение такое, что библиотека "заброшена".

Comment: "Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for android:exported when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined."

Comment: https://github.com/yandexmobile/yandex-login-sdk-android/blob/master/lib/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L30 Есть там exported